# WebException in Json Rest service call

Tags: json, windows-phone-8

An exception of type `System.Net.WebException` occurred in `System.Windows.ni.dll` but was not handled in user code.

Additional information: `The remote server returned an error: NotFound.`

Comment: It seems you are trying to access a web resource that does not exist (not found). Try to catch the exception and see if there is additional information in its exception message. Verify that the resource you are trying to access in fact exists, by accessing it with your browser.

Comment: http://www.catb.org/~esr/faqs/smart-questions.html